# What is the function space corresponding to the Gaussian-mixture parameter space?

Tags: gaussian-process, gaussian-mixture-distribution

If the parameter $\theta$ is Gaussian with mean $0$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, then the function $f(x;\theta)=x^T\theta$ is a Gaussian process indexed by $x$, which can be characterized by a mean function $\mathbf E[f(x)]=0$ and a covariance function $\mathbf{Cov}(f(x),f(x'))=x^T\Sigma x'$. If $\theta$ is a Gaussian mixture, what is $f(x;\theta)$? Is it a mixture of Gaussian processes? How can it be characterized?